# Missing value where TRUE FALSE value needed R ... not a duplicate! Aliens vs. Vampires Simulation

Tags: r, if-statement, simulation

Beginning R programmer here. I'm running a simulation of Aliens vs. Vampires and their domination of the human race.

Two stipulations to this simulation:

Aliens can abduct vampires. The amount is proportional to vampires current percentage of total world population (including humans).

Vampires have health requirements. They not only can transform humans into vampires but they also need some to feed on and kill...

I'm having trouble understanding this portion of code and why it is not working:

```
if (A[i-1] + A.prime * delta.t <= 0){
    A[i]<-0
  } else {
    A[i] <- A[i-1] + A.prime * delta.t 
  }
```

It is returning this error:

> Error in if (A[i - 1] + A.prime * delta.t <= 0) { :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed

Here is the entire code, I'm sure it is a simple code error and not a logical one. Any help would be appreciated!

```
# Aliens v. Vampires -- version 2.1
# (logistic growth with human reproduction)
# CPSC 420 -- spring 2016


# Set up time.
delta.t <- 1   # years
time <- seq(1940,3000,delta.t)

# Utility functions to convert between i and t.
itot <- function(i) (i-1)*delta.t + 1940
ttoi <- function(t) (t-1940)/delta.t + 1

# Simulation parameters.
init.human.pop <- 7e9
alien.abduction.rate <- 30000      # (beings/year)/year
bite.rate <- .1                # (people/year)/vampire
birth.rate <- .01              # (people/year)/person
sacrifice.rate<- .1 #people/year/vampire
#There is no specific rate for vampires being abducted per year because it is a portion of the alien abduction rate
A <- vector()
V <- vector()
H <- vector()
earth.population <- vector()
V.abductions<-vector()
sacrifice<- vector()

# Initial conditions. (No aliens until 1940, and only one lonely vampire.)
A[1] <- 0
V[1] <- 1
H[1] <- init.human.pop
earth.population[1] <- V[1] + H[1]
V.abductions[1]<-0
sacrifice[1]<-0


# Simulate.
for (i in 2:length(time)) {

  logistic.factor <- H[i-1]/earth.population[i-1]

  # Compute flows.
  VA.prime<-alien.abduction.rate * (time[i]-1940) * (V[i-1]/earth.population[i-1]) #vampires abducted/year
  sacrifice.prime<- sacrifice.rate * (V[i-1]) #sacrifice/year
  V.prime <- bite.rate * V[i-1] * logistic.factor - VA.prime# people/year
  A.prime <- alien.abduction.rate * (time[i] - 1940) * (logistic.factor) + VA.prime   # beings/year
  H.prime <- H[i-1] * birth.rate - (V.prime + (A.prime - VA.prime) + sacrifice.prime)    # people/year
  earth.population.prime <- -A.prime - sacrifice.prime    # people/year

  if(H[i-1] - sacrifice[i-1]<0){
    V.prime <- V.prime - (abs(sacrifice[i-1] - H[i-1])*sacrifice.rate)

  } else {
    V.prime <- bite.rate * V[i-1] * logistic.factor - VA.prime# people/year
  }


  # Compute stocks.
  if (A[i-1] + A.prime * delta.t <= 0){
    A[i]<-0
  } else {
    A[i] <- A[i-1] + A.prime * delta.t 
  }

  # people abducted

  if( V[i-1] + V.prime * delta.t <= 0 ) {
    V[i] <-0
  } else {
    V[i] <- V[i-1] + V.prime * delta.t 
  }               # vampires

  if(H[i-1] + H.prime * delta.t <= 0 ){
    H[i]<-0
  } else {
    H[i]<-H[i-1] + H.prime * delta.t
  } #humans left

  if(V[i] + H[i] <= 0 ){
    earth.population[i]<-0
    }else{
      earth.population[i] <- V[i] + H[i]
    } 

  # people

  V.abductions[i]<- V.abductions[i-1] + VA.prime * delta.t #total vampires abducted thus far
  sacrifice[i]<-sacrifice[i-1] + sacrifice.prime * delta.t #total victims sacrificed to vampires thus far 
}


# Plot results.
all.values <- c(A,V,H,earth.population)
plot(time,A,type="l",col="green",lwd=2,
     ylim=c(min(all.values),max(all.values)),
     main="Aliens v. Vampires apocalypse -- oh my!!",
     xlab="year",
     ylab="# of victims")
lines(time,V,col="red",lwd=2)
lines(time,H,col="black",lwd=1)
lines(time,earth.population,col="brown",lty="dotted",lwd=3)
lines(time,V.abductions,col="purple",lty="dashed",lwd=1)
lines(time,sacrifice,col="blue", lty = 3, lwd=1)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Alien abductions","Vampire bites","Humans","Earthlings", "Vampires Abducted","Human Victims"),
       fill=c("green","red","black","brown", "purple","blue"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `A[i-1] + A.prime * delta.t <= 0` evaluates to `NA`, and that raises an error. The `if` wants to know if it's `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and `NA` is neither.

`A.prime` is `NaN`, so that's where your problem starts. `A.prime` tests whether `A` is a prime number, but since it's a vector, this statement doesn't produce any value.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "A prime tests if A is a prime number" it's supposed to calculate a value and assign it to the vector A.prime

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that part in your code. Well then that part doesn't work, because after the assignment `A.prime` equals `NaN`. You should try and debug this assignment. Try parts of the expression first, and find out which parts of the assignments do not work the way you expect them to work.

Answer (score 0):

At some point (step i=336), earth.population has dropped to 0 so `logistic.factor` is division by 0 . Maybe you want to add a condition to enter the loop.